# How to throw Ember.js errors?

Tags: ember.js

In an ember.js application, how can we throw application errors (and have them bubble through the controller-route-application hierarchy?)

My use case is related to catching non ember-data ajax errors and handling them through the same path as ember data errors.

(i.e. when experiencing an error from a non-restful endpoint, allow that error to bubble through the application similar to ember-data errors)

Comment: Ember.assert(condition, "error description") this is what you looking for ?

Comment: Still struggling with this one. I will update as soon as I get some more information. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember has its own [EmberError](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/EmberError) class which sub classes the Javascript error class.

```
import EmberError from '@ember/error';

export default Route.extend({
  /* Pseudo code... */
  model() {
    if(/* something bad happens */) {
      throw new EmberError('Oh, no! Something bad happened!');
    }
  },
});
```

You can do something with it in an error action in your route. If you want it to bubble up, remember to return `true`.

```
actions: {
  error(error) {
    // do something
    return true;
  },
},
```

Ember automagically creates an error substate and a error template where you can display info about the error (without redirecting). You can show error info in `application-error.hbs` or `error.hbs` like so:

```
<h1>{{model.name}} {{model.status}}</h1>
{{model.stack}}
```

See the [Ember substate guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) for more options.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to throw errors, use `throw new Error("Message");`.

The user gets redirected to `error` route.

With Promises you can react on Exceptions, and handle them.

See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html

Comment: I think this should work, but in the case of Ajax errors I guess we'd have to forego the typical `.fail` handlers?

Comment: Not at all, JQuery Ajax call returns a promise, so if you return an ajax call in your routes model function, ember will hadle any errors. If you want to handle the error by yourself, use `.catch` instead of fail.

Comment: This is not redirecting me to the error route on ember 1.5.1, but loading works fine. Is error substate broken?